# Classification of syntax highlighting in sql server management studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If you can fill in the various types of things each color represents, I would really appreciate it :)

Blue text = commands, variable types

Red text = strings

Green text = comments

Pink text = functions?

Gray text = ???

Comment: All of the color definitions for syntax highlighting can be found in `Tools/Options/Environment/Fonts and Colors`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gray is variables, fields and object names,
pink - builtin functions and variables
Blue - T-Sql clauses, commands

Comment: When you do something like ... AS ThisVariable, "ThisVariable" is a normal variable?  If so, what is a variable that is preceded by an "@"?  What are the two types called?

Comment: No, thats alias for field, queriable object or expression in fields list

Comment: particular table only highlighted in green color in my case.Is there any special case?

Comment: @ManirajSS System objects are highlighted as green